# How to check celluar/wifi internet strength in Objective c?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, iot, internet-connection, alerts

I am developing an iot app ,I want to show a pop-up in case wifi/celluar internet is slow .
How to implement the slow networks alert in objective c ?

Comment: Check below link it may be useful to you   For Reachability http://stackoverflow.com/a/7938778/5184217  And check for slow internet http://stackoverflow.com/a/13910178/5184217

Answer (score 1):

I think you could try the [Reachbility](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) application to help you out checking if you have internet or not. As for the server itself, you can use the [NSUrlConnection Delegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSURLConnectionDelegate) methods to check if there was a problem with your request (by seeing the kind of HTTP code that comes)

```
Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
NetworkStatus internetStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];

if(internetStatus == NotReachable) {
UIAlertView *errorView;

errorView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
             initWithTitle: NSLocalizedString(@"Network error", @"Network error")
             message: NSLocalizedString(@"No internet connection found, this application requires an internet connection to gather the data required.", @"Network error")
             delegate: self
             cancelButtonTitle: NSLocalizedString(@"Close", @"Network error") otherButtonTitles: nil];

[errorView show];
[errorView autorelease];
}
```

Comment: This cannot determine the network status as slow or fast!

Comment: @TejaNandamuri check second answer.

Comment: Dont copy paste answers .Instead you can vote to close this as duplicate!

Comment: @TejaNandamuri okey

Answer (score 1):

**Full example to check internet connection.**

**please download [reachability class .h and .m](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) from here**

> Follow these steps

**viewcontroller.h**

```
@class Reachability;

@interface DashboardVC : UIViewController
{

Reachability* internetReachable;
Reachability* hostReachable;

}

-(void) checkNetworkStatus:(NSNotification *)notice;
```

**viewcontroller.m**

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
// check for internet connection
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(checkNetworkStatus:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];

internetReachable = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
[internetReachable startNotifier];

// check if a pathway to a random host exists
hostReachable = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"www.apple.com"];
[hostReachable startNotifier];

// now patiently wait for the notification
}


-(void) checkNetworkStatus:(NSNotification *)notice
{
// called after network status changes
NetworkStatus internetStatus = [internetReachable currentReachabilityStatus];
switch (internetStatus)
{
    case NotReachable:
    {
        NSLog(@"The internet is down.");

        break;
    }
    case ReachableViaWiFi:
    {
        NSLog(@"The internet is working via WIFI.");//your device is connected with wifi


        break;
    }
    case ReachableViaWWAN:
    {
        NSLog(@"The internet is working via WWAN.");//your internet is connected with mobile data


        break;
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send a request to your server and given that it's about 5-10 KB of data you expect to be returned, then create a timer callback that is scheduled for say 20 seconds.

If you don't get a response within 20 seconds, then let's consider that a slow connection.

```
// make POST request to server, the POST request should have a callback method assigned
[self testSpeed];

// schedule a method to be called after 20 seconds
myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithInterval:20.0 selector:@selector(stopSpeedTest) .... ];

// your POST request callback method
-(void)speedTestCallback
{
[myTimer invalidate];
myTimer = nil;

   [self alertGoodSpeed];
}

// your stopSpeedTest method to identify app didn't receive response within 20 seconds
-(void)stopSpeedTest
{
   [self alertTooSlow];
}
```